# Echo command in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, echo

echo "Hi There - Welcome to Docker POC">C:/Users/abc/xyz/POC/poc.html

The above echo command works from windows powershell but the same does not work when it is included in a Dockerfile as given below.

RUN echo "Hi There - Welcome to Docker POC">C:/Users/abc/xyz/POC/poc.html

The Error is    : System cannot find the path specified.

Pls help.

Comment: Have you copied the file to your docker image that you built?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the path you give at the end of the RUN command in the Dockerfile is into the container.

You probably want to run the command into a docker container. If so, please run:

```
docker run --rm -v C:/Users/abc/xyz/POC/:/POC busybox sh -c 'echo "Hi There - Welcome to Docker POC" > /POC/poc.html'
```

And you will see 'poc.html' file in 'C:/Users/abc/xyz/POC/'.

Tell if I misunderstood your request.